# Give an Executable Jar a Custom Image

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

Just finished a little app that I want to distribute and at the moment for windows platform it is just an executable jar. Is there anyway to give this jar another image than the java cup?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're referring to the way that the jar file shows up in Windows Explorer? If so, it's probably an OS setting (needing intervention on a machine-by-machine basis).

Comment: Suspected that :( Have to find me a nice exe wrapper then.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the image in whatever file manager you are using, then it is provider by your OS. If you are talking about the icon in the application's window, you can change it with Window.setIconImage

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shortcut to the JAR file, and then you can change the shortcut's icon.

Comment: windows shortcuts contains absolute paths, including drive letter (making them less than ideal for distribution, unfortunately).